# Unable to find dllimports at run time MSTest c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, dllimport

I am using `MSTest` to carry out some integration testing together with some hardware. I place my `dll` files in the `/bin/debug` path (the same path as the test executable). However when I create an object and call a certain function that requires the `dll` import, I am unable to find the `dll` file. I am using relative path for my `dll`, hence I expect that the test program should locate my `dll`’s in the test executable folder.

Is there a way to examine which directory the test executable looks for when running the tests?

Comment: You should add your dll as reference instead of directly placing `\bin\debug`

Comment: I can’t add as reference because it is a native dll. I get an error sth like “not a valid assembly and com component error”

Comment: Than have a look at [DeploymentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) in MSTest

Comment: The OS needs to find that DLL, it will not look in bin\Debug.  Modifying the PATH environment variable to help it find it is normally not a great idea, but is practical in the case of a unit test.  Use Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() in the [TestInitialize] method.

Comment: why would relative path for files work in MSTest but not for dllimport? I am able to read a file using the relative path to the /bin/debug folder

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve my problem by following this tutorial online.

`https://robor78.wordpress.com/2016/07/04/add-a-deployment-item-to-a-c-unit-test/`

What I did was I added the native dll's, "bwteklz.dll" and "EFCam.dll" to my project.

[image]

Then for each dll that i added, I set the copy to output directory to "always". [image]

I didn't need to use the `[deployItem]` attribute for my testing.

Still rather confused by the `[deployItem]` attribute not needing to be used in this case.